# How I can load google map with jquery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to load google map with customized markers with jquery `$post()` request, the page is working fine but it is not working with `$post`, here is the sample code which I am trying to load 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex
and this is how I am calling it

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $.post('map.php',{state:3,id:1},function(data){
         $("#map").html(data);
    });
```

Comment: The JS you posted is invalid, you're missing a closing `});`  I've edited your indentation to make it more obvious... it's probably just a cut-and-paste error rather than an actual mistake in your code, right?

Comment: @duncan this is a mistake, but is good in my original code. appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In this way you are setting the content of the map id with the result (`data`) of the `$.post(..)` not with the map. I think you need to rewrite the function with a proper generation of the map or an invocation of an equivalent function.